# How do I access class variables?

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter

In this program I want a user to enter credentials and then based on the inputs validate whether it is correct. I am using tkinter to provide a GUI. I want to be able to take the auth function outside of the class so I can shut the tkinter dialog once the account has been logged in, however, the problem here is that the auth function is within the class, I've tried various ways to retrieve the variable but I've had no luck.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tm

class LoginFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.label_Email = Label(self, text="Email")
        self.label_password = Label(self, text="Password")

        self.entry_Email = Entry(self)
        self.entry_password = Entry(self, show="*")

        self.label_Email.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
        self.label_password.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
        self.entry_Email.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entry_password.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.checkbox = Checkbutton(self, text="Keep me logged in")
        self.checkbox.grid(columnspan=2)

        self.logbtn = Button(self, text="Login", command=self._login_btn_clicked)
        self.logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)

        self.pack()

    def _login_btn_clicked(self):
        # print("Clicked")
        Email = self.entry_Email.get()
        password = self.entry_password.get()

        # print(Email, password)

        self.answer = auth(Email, password)



root = Tk()
lf = LoginFrame(root)

if 'Bearer' in lf.answer:
    root.quit()

root.mainloop()
```

My auth function will return a bearer token for the next stage if the login is successful, therefore I am checking whether or not the answer variable has returned it. If it has then I will shut the tkinter dialog

Comment: The problem here is that `if 'Bearer' in lf.answer` actually runs before your GUI is even displayed when you call mainloop function. You'd have to make the frame know how to quit itself during button click

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing the instance variable correctly, just in the wrong "order". Meaning, the answer must be checked only after the button is clicked. Basically, when your GUI loads, or directly after making the frame, the button isn't clicked, so the variable isn't defined, yet you're trying to access it immediately

One simple option is to not access the instance variable, and just use the passed in Tk object of the master

```
def _login_btn_clicked(self):
    # print("Clicked")
    Email = self.entry_Email.get()
    password = self.entry_password.get()

    # print(Email, password)

    answer = auth(Email, password)
    if 'Bearer' in answer:
        self.master.quit()
```